# Many problems booting Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot

I'm a first time Linux user, I tried installing Mint and now Ubuntu on my laptop and I'm having some problems I think are related to my graphics card.
The laptop is a DV6-6135dx with an AMD Quad-Core A83500M Accelerated processor and Switchable Graphics (Radeon HD 6750M & Radeon HD 6620G).

First startup the errors are:

```
No irq handler for vector 
mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
*ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
```

Sometimes it boots, sometimes it freezes in the screen with the 22.04 and the dots changing color.

The solution I found online for the UVD error is to edit the GRUB and set

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="radeon.modeset=0"
```

Where it previously was empty between the quotes.
This eliminated the UVD error but created a new one in adition to the other two:

```
 *ERROR* No UMS support in radeon module!
```

When booting with that option it goes to a black screen with a blinking "underscore" and never boots.
Same thing happens If i use "nomodeset" instead of "radeon.modeset=0"

As I said, I'm new to Linux so I don't really know what all this options do.
Thanks!

Comment: First you need to understand what nomodeset does. https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/grub-options.html#:~:text=Adding%20the%20nomodeset%20parameter%20instructs,instead%20until%20X%20is%20loaded. In short it turns off all video card drivers.

Comment: You need to install the correct driver for the GPU that you are using. That should clear up all of the issues as described in your question. I am assuming that you are using Ubuntu at this point.

Comment: David, I downloaded the drivers from AMD and when I try to install them an error says I can't install it because of some packages unmet dependencies, but it does not list any packages.

Comment: @David - AMD graphics drivers are supported at the kernel level, and attempting to install them manually generally results in a broken system...